# Speed up a distortion of 4k image

Tags: performance-tuning

I want to undistort 4032 x 3024 image with OpenCV model using only radial distortion. This model is described [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html).

The main issue is the speed.
I have a function `distort` that takes all the execution time:

```
distort[{x_, y_}, {k1_, k2_, k3_, k4_, k5_, k6_}] :=
    With[{r2 = x^2 + y^2},
        With[{r4 = r2^2, r6 = r2^3},
            With[{s = (1 + k1 r2 + k2 r4 + k3 r6) / (1 + k4 r2 + k5 r4 + k6 r6)}, s {x, y}]]];
```

Distortion of one point on my laptop takes about 0.00002 seconds. So I have about 12M points and the total time is 12M * 0.00002 s ~ 4 minutes.

Any ideas how to speed up the computations?

P. S. A piece of code to test program:

```
{imageWidth, imageHeight} = {4032, 3024};
dictortionCoefficientsRadial = {0.0488079, -0.140193, 0.144845, 0, 0, 0};
cameraMatrix = {{3137.35, 0, 1990.53}, {0, 3143.89, 1514.04}, {0, 0, 1}};

AbsoluteTiming[distort[{1, 1}, dictortionCoefficientsRadial]]

pointsImage = Tuples[{Range[0, imageWidth - 1], Range[0, imageHeight - 1], {1}}];
pointsZ1 = pointsImage . Transpose[Inverse[cameraMatrix][[{1, 2}]]];
pointsZ1Distorted = Curry[distort][dictortionCoefficientsRadial] /@ pointsZ1;
```

Comment: Have you tried using `ParallelMap` instead of `/@`? As well, using `Developer\`ToPackedArray` may help.

Comment: @CarlLange Yes, I did. `ParallelMap[Curry[distort][dictortionCoefficientsRadial], Developer\`ToPackedArray[widePointsZ1]]` worked about 9 minutes.

Answer (score 6):

Compile is your friend in this case:

```
cf = Compile[{{X, _Real, 1}, {k, _Real, 1}},
 Block[{r2, s, x, y},
  x = X[[1]];
  y = X[[2]];
  r2 = x^2 + y^2;
  s = Divide[
    1. + r2 (k[[1]] + r2 (k[[2]] + k[[3]] r2)), 
    1. + r2 (k[[4]] + r2 (k[[5]] + k[[6]] r2))
    ];
  {s x, s y}],
 CompilationTarget -> "C",
 RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
 Parallelization -> True,
 RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
 ];
```

Now you use it as follows:

```
{imageWidth, imageHeight} = {4032, 3024};
dictortionCoefficientsRadial = Developer`ToPackedArray[N[{0.0488079, -0.140193, 0.144845, 0, 0, 0}]];
cameraMatrix = Developer`ToPackedArray[N[{{3137.35, 0, 1990.53}, {0, 3143.89, 1514.04}, {0, 0, 1}}]];

pointsImage = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {imageWidth, imageHeight, 3}];
pointsZ1 = pointsImage.Transpose[Inverse[cameraMatrix][[{1, 2}]]];
pointsZ1Distorted2 = cf[pointsZ1, dictortionCoefficientsRadial]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.729514

Done in under a second.

Due to the option `RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}`, `cf` threads over matrices so that we need not flatten out the image anymore. So we have

```
Dimensions[pointsZ1Distorted2]
```

> {4032, 3024, 2}

## Edit

I put numerator and denominator of `s` into `HornerForm`. In principle, this should save us a few floating point multiplications, but it does not really make a difference here.

Comment: Why do you have both 1 in `{{X, _Real, 1}, {k, _Real, 1}}`? Should it be 2, 6?

Comment: The `1` stands for the tensor rank of a tensor. `1` means, it is a vector. Size of the tensor arguments can be requested from within the function with `Dimension`.

Comment: This is actually something for which GPU programming _might_ be very useful...